# Why are object stored in Heap

Tags: java

Why are objects stored in heap?

As per my understanding, an object gets stored in Heap and a reference variable holds the address of the object.

Reference variable is stored in stack. If the reference variable is deleted then object becomes unreachable. So theoretically, object is also dead. (ofcourse, when there is only one reference variable referencing to the object).

So my confusion is what did make it necessary to store the object in heap ?

Comment: What's your proposed alternative, bearing in mind that the reference may be returned, or used elsewhere as well? Note that these days JITs can sometimes be smart enough to store the object on the stack when they *know* it will never escape - but it's easier to *think* of it as being on the heap.

Comment: 'cos they fall over if you try to put them in a neat stack :-)

Comment: Thanks @Jon ... JIT thing cleared my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You mean in Java, right?

- stack slice's life cycle is during a function call,
- stack usually only store types that has fix size, e.g interger, pointer,
- stack is small,
- stack is usually visible to its thread, not suitable for global variables,

By the way, JVM is base on OS, typically, on unix-like system, there are stack & heap & mmap, JVM implementation make use of the underling OS interface, and thus memory model of JVM is kind of similar to OS in some aspect.